# Accessing ENV variable in spec helper

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails

Is it an expected behavior that with `rspec-rails (6.0.3)` at the top of `spec_helper.rb` I'm not able to get my environment variables?

I'm trying to set `simplecov` to run only on CI and, as I have done many times in the past (with older RSpec versions), I added `require 'simplecov' if ENV['CI'] == "true"` at the very top of `spec_helper.rb`. However, this time around ENV['CI'] is not defined even if my `.env.test` file looks like

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://...
CI=true
```

If I add below the `require ...` line, `puts ENV['CI']` I got an empty line

```
sig@mbc app % bin/rspec spec

.

Finished in 1.66 seconds (files took 2.03 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

and if I add `puts ENV` instead of getting an hash I get `ENV`.

```
sig@mbc app % bin/rspec spec
ENV
.

Finished in 1.64 seconds (files took 1.93 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Boolean/string comparisons might be the problem here. Just check if the variable existing instead: `if ENV['CI'] ...`. Then you can set it to `1`, `true`, `foobar` or whatever you feel like.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `.env.test`, it looks you use dotenv gem

Check your Gemfile gem notation

If this line is not on to the top of the file, move it there (in global section)

```rb
gem 'dotenv-rails', require: 'dotenv/rails-now'
```